# Having an HTML form which has two submit buttons

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

Basically, the form will have a single same action, but depending on the button that is clicked , I need to send a hidden field value with button1, but not with button2 submit. Any way to do this?

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: I need to confirm if there is a way where this is possible before trying...

Answer (score 3):

Just store the values on the submit buttons.

```
<button name="foo" value="bar"> Button 1 </button>
<button> Button 2 </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
   <input name="input1">
   <input name="input2">

   <button name="submit" value="submit1">Submit</button>
   <button name="submit" value="submit2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit1') {
   // code with input1
} else if ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit2') {
   // code with input2
}
```

if you submit form by pressing enter, submit1 will be default value

Answer (score 0):

Give different name for your button, for example `"button1"` and `"button2"`, and when you click that button with the name `"button1"` , you can save the hidden field value, if you click `"button2"` just ignore the hidden field.